# Why is asp-route passing on post value "0"

Tags: asp.net-core, parameter-passing, tag-helpers

In my razor page in form I have button that on submit calls method "OnPostEditMe" with parameter "int id":

```
@{ 
    var idbook = @Html.DisplayFor(a => a.EditBook.Id);
    //idbook on page load gets id number of object EditBook when page loads, this works, if I add this value anywhere in razor page it displays correctly 
}

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-3 offset-3">
            <button asp-page-handler="EditMe" asp-route-id="@idbook" type="submit"> 
                    Update @idbook
            </button>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I click on this button, It calls method OnPostEditMe, but with parameter "0" instead value that was load with "idbook":

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditMe(int id)
{
    var tmp = id; //id is always 0
    ...
}
```

What is wrong, Why does asp-route-id="@idbook" not passing parameter that was load on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set on the `form` instead of the button

```
<form method="post" asp-route-id="@idbook">
```

Or you can use hidden input

```
 <input value="@idbook" name="id" id="id" type="hidden"/>.
```

Comment: Ok <input value="@idbook" name="id" id="id" type="hidden" /> works, but why with tag-helper "asp-route" not?